# Disconnected from Phoenix channel when sending multiple large messages in a small time frame

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, large-data, channel

First of all I'd like to say that at my company we are huge fans of the Elixir ecosystem and particularly of the Phoenix framework.

#### Context

- A Phoenix app called "the broker" exposing a channel
- A Phoenix app called "the client" connecting to the broker channel using the package phoenix_gen_socket_client (see https://hex.pm/packages/phoenix_gen_socket_client)

#### Environment

Broker app : 
    Elixir 1.5.1
    Phoenix v1.3
    Freebsd jail v10.3 amd64

Client app : 
    Elixir 1.5.1
    Phoenix v1.3
    Mac os X

#### Problem

When sending multiple messages over the channel, using for example a loop or Enum.each, only few messages manage to get to the broker channel handle_in function.
  Then the client crash with the following error:

> 21:45:58.027 [error] ** State machine #PID<0.471.0> terminating   **
>   Last message in was {:send_frame,    {:binary,
>       <<31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 188, 187, 231, 206, 235, 74, 146, 45, 248,
>         42, 131, 51, 63, 217, 183, 232, 93, 253, 163, 104, 69, 47, 209, 115, 106,
>         80, 160, 247, 222, 179, 113, 223, 125, 184, 247, 62, 231, 84, ...>>}}   ** When State == :connected   **      Data  == {:context,
>   {:websocket_req, :wss, 'broker.dexyde.com', 443,
>       '/socket/websocket?user_token=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAACZAAEZGF0YW4HAIClCS9hXAVkAAZzaWduZWRuBgC9YkVUXwE.ZRbhkBm4BxzGEXLynPpfXDuGTcuZQMdhgcJszmZd3zo',
>       30000, :undefined, 1,
>       {:sslsocket, {:gen_tcp, #Port<0.20422>, :tls_connection, :undefined},
>        #PID<0.476.0>},
>       {:transport, :ssl, :ssl, :ssl_closed, :ssl_error,
>        [mode: :binary, active: true, verify: :verify_none, packet: 0]},
>       "12krm8DaxFlr/ZuaS8p6Uw==", 139669, 1, 2, :undefined, :undefined},    {:transport, :ssl, :ssl, :ssl_closed, :ssl_error,
>       [mode: :binary, active: true, verify: :verify_none, packet: 0]}, [],    {:wss, 'broker.dexyde.com', 443,
>       '/socket/websocket?user_token=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAACZAAEZGF0YW4HAIClCS9hXAVkAAZzaWduZWRuBgC9YkVUXwE.ZRbhkBm4BxzGEXLynPpfXDuGTcuZQMdhgcJszmZd3zo'},
>   {Phoenix.Channels.GenSocketClient.Transport.WebSocketClient,
>       %{keepalive: 30000, socket: #PID<0.469.0>}},    <<31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 188, 187, 231, 206, 235, 90, 118, 45, 248,
>        42, 141, 211, 63, 105, 155, 57, 213, 63, 138, 81, 204, 18, 51, 187, 26, 5,
>        230, 156, 51, 141, 251, 238, 151, ...>>, false, :undefined, 0}   ** Reason for termination =   ** {:error, :closed}

We are using binary messages with custom serializer on the broker side.
  The observed size of the payload is, before zipping it, between 500K and 1M character.

#### Tests done

- Add a :timer.sleep(3000) between each push from the client so that the messages arrive in the handle_in function of the broker and it can reply to the handle_reply of the client.
- Reducing the size of the message payload seems to work too.

#### Our conclusion...so far

It seems that when a client app is sending multiple large messages over the channel in a small time frame, it got disconnected from the broker channel.

#### Questions

- Do anybody has already experience something similar when sending many large message in a small time frame ?
- Is there a kind of channel or socket limitations to be known ?

Any though or remarks are most welcome on this subject.

Many thanks for your help.

Regards,

Julien

Comment: Just a wild guess: haven’t you tried spawning a `Task` with a payload to be able to immediately answer with `{:noreply, socket}`?

Comment: Yes tried it. Same problem, the payload won't enter in the handle_in function of the server channel.

Comment: Yes, I also experienced that. It happens very frequently if you type like a bot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share the interesting answers I got from elixir forum:

https://elixirforum.com/t/disconnected-from-phoenix-channel-when-sending-multiple-large-messages-in-a-small-time-frame/9661/3